# Launch locally script on remote SSH

Tags: ssh, applescript

Is possible to launch an Applescript stored locally on remote trough SSH protocol without copy it on remote machine?
I have a file.scpt on my rapspberry. i want to launch the file via ssh on my mac. But i' m not able to do this. I've tried with following command lines:

```
ssh -T server "bash" < ./file.scpt
ssh server <  osascript "./file.scpt"
ssh server <  cat ./file.scpt| osascript
```

I've also tried to export my script as an exec file, but i can't launch the script over ssh.
I don't have problem with ssh. The connection between two hosts is established by the same RSA-Key

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
ssh <servername>.local 'osascript "<path to script>/thescript.scpt"'
```

and it works fine.

(For testing purposes, I have a script that touches a file on the remote server and returns success or failure:

```
try
    do shell script "/usr/bin/touch '/Users/<username>/sshTest.txt'"
on error
    return "failure"
end try
return success
```

Comment: I've just realised that it seems you want to execute an AppleScript stored on the Pi without copying to the remote Mac.  It would help if you would explain what the script does.  There might be a better way than using ssh for this.